# Is it that a complete project just has only one collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, dbase

In my organization I am given a task to combine my DBase(RDBMS) tables to MongoDB(NoSQL) collection.
There are multiple tables in my DBase tables and I have to combine them into just one collection with mapping the fields from Dbase tables.

And another question is :
Is it that a mongoDB collection always an nested insert operation is performed instead of updating the particular document.

Answer (score 0):

No, you may have multiple collections for your project. For example: `orders_collection` and `user_collection`, which may (but it is not mandatory) to be in the same database.

No. You can run update operation, which will update one field of a specific document. 
More here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Thanks for help @djaszczurowski...
But I am being said from my projectManager that i have to only perform insert operations to manage history data.
How am i supposed to do that